# cross-platform file structure handling

Tags: c++, file-io, cross-platform, cross-compiling

Whenever I need to define a file structure, I'm using compiler-specific commands (like `#pragma pack(1)`) to ensure that I can safely read and write this file and don't need to worry about padding issues.

However, is there any other way to reach the same goal? I don't need to de-/serialize complex objects, just POD types.

Comment: What are you doing about endianness?

Comment: @JasonD - Currently: Nothing. I assume little-endian. However, this is indeed not very platform-independent.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to define a cross-platform binary format that always nicely maps to the in-memory representation of types.

The two options for defining cross-platform file formats are:

1. Use text
2. Define a binary format in terms of what your favourite cross-platform serialisation library can provide and use that library to convert the file contents between their internal and external representation.

Comment: Or, 3. Make it up yourself as the OP is already doing, but be sure you "document" for yourself and/or others what the endianness, type sizes, and order are so that your format can be encoded and decoded on other platforms. (I've done this lots but always find that for anything of any complexity or expected longevity, I always end up migrating to something more standardized.)

Comment: @BenZotto: I would not consider that a *cross-platform* file format. There are just too many variables to document. And otherwise it uses a 'home-brewn' serialisation library.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost Serialization Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) might be an option, if you want it to be solved fast and without much ado.